# Animation-delay then pseudo class before?

Tags: css, css-animations

Is there a way to use the 'animation-delay' (of the transition-delay) to make a delay of few seconds and then change the :before of the same element?

What i want to do is when user held the button for more then few second(:active state) make a change to the :before. (I want to switch the button web-icon).

Is that possible? any other alternative ? I don't want to use js.

here is what I mean,I want the before to happend only after 2s.

```
&:active {
    -webkit-animation-name: spaceboots;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.8s;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-animation-delay: 2s;
    -o-animation-delay: 2s;
    animation-delay: 2s;
    width: 45px;

    &:before {
        content: "now text show";
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share some HTML?

Comment: Could you set the opacity of the before to 0 initially, set it to 1 in the active:before, and add an animation-delay of 2s to it as well?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example using the `transition` property to do what you describe.

```
a:before {
    background-color:red;
}

a:active:before {
    /* the background will transition quickly after 3 seconds */
    transition-delay:2s;
    background-color:green;
}
```

[**here is an example**](http://jsfiddle.net/pLzuh092/)

Comment: You can just change the transition delay on each state rather than using keyframes for different delays.

Answer (score 1):

Check this updated **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j0o22s05/2/)**

Rather than replace the `content` property, leverage both the `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements and have one come in delayed over the other instead.  You could also have one fade out when the other fades in by basically doing the opposite (if you don't have solid backgrounds).

```
a {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 16px;
    position: relative;
}

a:before,
a:after {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 100%;
    width: 16px;
}

a:before {
    background-color: blue;
    content: '1';
}

a:after {
    background-color: green;
    content: '2';
    visibility:hidden;
    opacity:0;
    transition:visibility 0s linear 0.5s,opacity 0.5s linear;
}

a:active:after {
    visibility:visible;
    opacity:1;
    transition-delay:1s;
}
```